# HVAC wont turn on heat

Tags: heating, nest

I recently installed NEST thermostat and the cooling aspect was Ok, however now when i turn on the heat, the thermostat says its heating however there is still cold air coming thru the vents. After inspecting the wires at the furnace, i found no wire in W terminal, is this common and also the Yellow wire was connected to an unmarked terminal, See pics attached. [image]

Comment: There should be a wiring diagram in there somewhere.  Include that and a picture of your Nest diagram.

Comment: what type of heating do you have ?

Comment: The "W" wire is the call for HEAT.  But if it's not connected, then the usual reason is that you have a split/dual system where you have an A/C and a separate furnace.

Comment: @jwh20  Type that up as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my Nest 1st gen.

It turns out I did not connect the **O/B** terminal on the Nest.

That one will activate the reversal valve in the outdoor unit, switching from cooling to heating.

Since it provides limited heating, some (like you) need separate heat furnace.

Usually the **W** on Nest is to activate the Furnace.

You have

Y-cooling

W- (Heating) not used

R- 24 Volt (with 3 consumers) Nest is one of them)

G- Fan in the Condenser

C- common (3 consumers)

and TWIN- with 2 wires (normally to control two furnaces

It would be recommended to connect the W from Nest to the W on the control board.

Comment: One comment about reversing valves.  Some systems are built so when the reversing valve is de-energized, the system is in HEAT mode.  On other systems, the de-energized position is COOL.